# Mailmerge Field not always saved the same way in Word .docx

Tags: ms-word, word-field, fieldcodes

I have created a Word document with Word 2003 and inserted some MergeField via the GUI.
I have saved it as a .docx by using *Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint 2007 File Formats*. Some Mergefields are stored as a SimpleField, while others are stored as a FieldCode (with start-FieldChar and end-FieldChar). Some Googling brought me to this [blog](http://tradeoffz.blogspot.com/2007/11/docx-format-mail-merge.html). As you can see the guy is facing the same problem; but hasn't found a solution yet.

I'm using the following code sample on Codeplex [Fill Mergefields] to replace the MergeFields with the actual values from different datasources.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If a field's value is just simple text with consistent formatting, it can be stored as a fldSimple node. However, if the field's value has varying formatting, it has to be saved as a complex field (fldChar Start, Optional Separate, and End) so that each run within the field's value can have it's different formatting defined in the run properties `<w:rPr>`. I think that also happens if word uses the `rsid` attributes to track changes. The fldChar Start/Separate/End are also necessary if the fields are nested, such as multiple IF fields, so that it can store an arbitrary number of `<w:r>`, `<w:p>`, `<w:tbl>` as the field's value.

And sometimes it stores them like that for seemingly no good reason. (As that blog noted).